# How to integrate D3.js with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller, d3.js

I am new to backbone.js and I am trying to integrate my work to backbone.js structure. As far as I know the point is to separate the codes in to an MVC pattern and I have some html files that are mainly based on javascript code. For example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1256572 I want to make model and view for it. I have found some examples but this one is complicated, for example, draw() function should be in model or view? Or even the function that is used to update the data. I do not know how to separate them in backbone.

Answer (score 0):

All the d3 functions should be contained in a view, the data in a model.